# BULK Insert Fails with different files sizes

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have this problem where bulk insert fails with different files sizes, specifically, the first file would contain 433 rows while the second file has 2 rows only. But when I insert the 2 rowed file by itself, there's no error.

I have this as my bulk insert statement

```
set @sql =   'BULK INSERT #temptable
    FROM '''+@location+'''
    WITH
    (
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '','',  
    ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'',
    MAXERRORS = 100,
    TABLOCK,
    FIRSTROW = 2
    )'
```

The above statement is contained in a stored procedure.

For more information, I will put my stored procedure here.

```
USE [THERMOWAVE]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[UploadOmronData]    Script Date: 02/13/2017 13:48:54 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[UploadOmronData] 

@location as nvarchar(max)

as

begin
declare @sql as nvarchar(max)
-- give @location data from VB.net
 --declare @location as varchar(max)
 --set @location = 'C:\Users\jsumgo\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TestUploader\TestUploader\bin\Debug\12320161428420dataUpload.csv'
-- Joshua Magsino 11/28/2016
-- TSql to upload dynamic column data source

--before uploading, make sure that datasource table columns are named equal to database table column
--Check if data is to be stored as reference or could be destroyed
--Check database to store and columns that would be affected

--set configurations to enable Ad Hoc Distributed Queries
/*
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
RECONFIGURE;
GO 
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO  
*/
-- configure SQL to execute Ad Hoc Queries using MSOFFICE 2010
/*
USE [master] 
GO 
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'AllowInProcess', 1 
GO 
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'DynamicParameters', 1 
GO  
*/


-- fill temptable with data

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--drop table #temptable
--create blank temptable
create table #temptable
(
[Number] Varchar(20)
)

--declare @sql as varchar(max)
declare @cursor CURSOR
declare @colname as nvarchar(30)
SET @cursor = CURSOR FOR 
(Select colname from dbo.sorting)

OPEN @cursor

FETCH NEXT

FROM @cursor INTO @colname
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
-- add from column 2 to end
if @colname <> 'Number'
    begin
        set @sql = 'ALTER TABLE #temptable ADD ['+@colName+'] NVARCHAR(max) NULL'
        EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@colname nvarchar(max)', @colname 
    end


FETCH NEXT
FROM @cursor INTO @colName
END

CLOSE @cursor
DEALLOCATE @cursor

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

--declare @location as varchar(max)
--set @location = 'D:\Omron Data\Data\sample\asdasdasdasdasd - Copy.csv'
--declare @sql as varchar(max)
--Insert Data from CSV file to Temptable
set @sql =   'BULK INSERT #temptable
    FROM '''+@location+'''
    WITH
    (
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '','',  
    ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'',
    MAXERRORS = 100,
    TABLOCK,
    FIRSTROW = 2
    )'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@location as nvarchar(max)', @location 

--Insert Statement
--If the location of the new column is in the last column of the CSV file, then direct bulk insert
--safe solution is to insert based on the column name of each table
--cursor is needed

DECLARE @DBcursor CURSOR
DECLARE @DBColname as varchar(30)
DECLARE @DBCOL as nvarchar(max)

--Get Table Names from dbo.sorting
--since all table names are inserted from dbo.sorting, get column names from dbo.sorting
SET @DBcursor = CURSOR FOR 
(Select colname from dbo.sorting)

OPEN @DBcursor

FETCH NEXT
FROM @DBcursor INTO @DBColname
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

--assemble columns
set @DBCOL = (isnull(@DBCOL,''))+'['+ @DBColname +'],'

FETCH NEXT
FROM @DBcursor INTO @DBColname
END

CLOSE @DBcursor
DEALLOCATE @DBcursor
--remove last (,) from columns
set @DBCOL =LEFT(@DBCOL, LEN(@DBCOL) - 1)
--insert data from temptable to DataUpload



set @sql = 'insert into DataToUpload  ('+@DBCOL+')  select '+@DBCOL+' from #tempTable'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql,N'@DBCOL NVARCHAR(max)', @DBCOL

--Put BatchID for DataUpload
--BatchId format,Batch + Number(000) + year + month + day
declare @number as nvarchar(max)
set @number = RIGHT('000' +CAST((select  ISNULL(max(case when BatchID = null or BatchID = '' then '000' else right(SUBSTRING(BatchID,1,8),3)+ 1 end),'000') from DataToUpload)AS VARCHAR(3)),3)
set @sql = 'update DataToUpload set BatchID = ''Batch'+cast(@number as varchar(max))+cast(year(getdate()) as varchar(4))+''+cast(MONTH(getdate())as varchar(2))+''+cast(DAY(getdate())as varchar(2)) +''' where BatchID is null'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql,N'@number NVARCHAR(max)', @number

--select * from DataToUpload order by BAtchID,Number asc
--select * from dbo.Sorting
--select * from temptable
--delete from DataToUpload

--clear dbo.sorting
delete from dbo.Sorting

--remove temptable
drop table #temptable

DBCC FREEPROCCACHE WITH NO_INFOMSGS;  


end
```

and then the command in a vb.net system that fires the stored procedure through here.

```
 Sub UploadOmronData(ByVal location As String)
        'SQL Stored Procedure -- Save data from CSV file to SQL
        Dim sqlcom As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
        Try
            With sqlcom
                conn.Open()
                .Connection = conn
                .CommandTimeout = 100
                .CommandText = "dbo.UploadOmronData"
                .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@location", location)
                .ExecuteReader()
            End With

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message + " " + location)
            GC.Collect()
            sqlcom.Dispose()
            frmMain.Close()
        End Try
        conn.Close()
        sqlcom.Dispose()
        GC.Collect()
    End Sub
```

And the error message which I receive:

```
Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 2, column 1 (Number).

Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 3, column 1 (Number).
```

ADDED INFORMATION

Here is the table structure of dbo.DataToUpload

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DataToUpload](
    [Number] [int] NULL,
    [Date&Time] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ms] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CH34] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CH35] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CH36] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CH37] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CH38] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CH39] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Alarm1-10] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Alarm11-20] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Alarm21-30] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Alarm31-40] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [AlarmOut] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [BatchID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CH31] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [CH32] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [CH33] [nvarchar](20) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

and the rows that I'm trying to insert

```
Number,Date&Time,ms,CH34,CH35,CH36,CH37,CH38,CH39,Alarm1-10,Alarm11-20,Alarm21-30,Alarm31-40,AlarmOut
1,2016-08-08 16:23:16,000,+61.2,+64.0,+35.4,+94.4,+185.4,+151.2,LLLLLLLLLL,LLLLLLLLLL,LLLLLLLLLL,LLLLLLLLLL,LLLL
2,2016-08-08 16:23:26,000,+61.1,+64.4,+35.4,+94.3,+185.4,+151.2,LLLLLLLLLL,LLLLLLLLLL,LLLLLLLLLL,LLLLLLLLLL,LLLL
```

and If it mayhelp, the system I created is a background worker, since I have to run the code always.

Comment: The error message is telling you the problem.  Whatever the structure of your "Number" field is in the "DataToUpload" table, it's not large enough to cope with the string length you're trying to insert into it.   Can you show us the structure of your DataToUpload table, and what values you're attempting to insert in this, from rows 2 & 3.

Comment: @MikeGledhill Thank you for your reply! I have added the information which you asked, thank you again.

Comment: `[Date&Time] [nvarchar](max)` Don't do that, use appropriate datatypes. If you  want to store a date and time, use `datetime`. It'll save a lot of hassle in the future.

Comment: @HoneyBadger Thank you Sir for pointing it out, I will change that immediately after solving the current problem, I might encounter other problems when I change it now.

Comment: It gets me thinking that, why are there files which I could upload while there are files which I could not upload. Uploading meaning bulk insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reckon the cause is that you're asking `BULK INSERT` to load 14 columns of data, but you're importing into `#TempTable` which doesn't have enough fields in it.

Your code creates a `#tempTable` table, and you use a `CURSOR` to add extra fields to it... but I reckon the end result *isn't* a table with 14 fields in it.

Before your `BULK INSERT #temptable` command gets run, how many fields are in the `#temptable` table ?

For example, if you just had one field in this table, when you ran the bulk-insert it would insist on trying to import *the entire row* into that one field, complete with all the commas, but, of course, it doesn't fit in a 20-character string.

```
CREATE TABLE #temptable
(
    [Number] VARCHAR(20)
)
```

The solution... simply change your temporary table to have the correct number of columns, and the BULK INSERT *will* work fine:

```
CREATE TABLE #temptable
(
    [Number] NVARCHAR(200),
    [Datey] datetime,
    [ms] NVARCHAR(200),
    [CH34] NVARCHAR(200),
    [CH35] NVARCHAR(200),
    [CH36] NVARCHAR(200),
    [CH37] NVARCHAR(200),
    [CH38] NVARCHAR(200),
    [CH39] NVARCHAR(200),
    [Alarm110] NVARCHAR(200),
    [Alarm1120] NVARCHAR(200),
    [Alarm2130] NVARCHAR(200),
    [Alarm3140] NVARCHAR(200),
    [AlarmOut] NVARCHAR(200)
)
```

Good luck !

P.S. One piece of the puzzle which is missing....  What data do you have in your `dbo.sorting` table ?  This will dictate which fields end up in your temporary table, but you don't explain how this table is populated, or what data it contains.

Comment: Hi Sir Mike, Good day, `dbo.sorting` is populated through another stored procedure, it gets the column names of the CSV file and puts it in a table, and the table in return will add the column to the temptable. But I will check your answer sir, Kindly wait for the results.

Comment: As a follow up question, how can you create a temptable using a stored procedure? I tried `@sql = 'create #temptable` then `exec(@sql)` but the stored proc does not seem to find the table, but when I create a physical table like `@sql = 'create temptable` then `exec(@sql)` it works. and thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

The attributes

```
[BatchID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[CH31] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[CH32] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[CH33] [nvarchar](20) NULL
```

are missing from your file. With `BULK_INSERT` the columns have to match perfectly. Fix the number of columns, and it should fix the error.

Comment: Hi Sir! Thank you, but the batchID is like my audit trail and I cannot insert it to a program produced by a machine, the 3 other fields are not common to some files because some situations would not require more fields, which the machine can only control. But with this regard, I could still insert other records which may or may not have CH31 to CH33 and I can insert data without BatchID.

Comment: I don't follow everything in your last comment, but the point is for bulk_insert all columns have to match. If you can't make the match, you'll have to insert in another (temp) table first.